# what's the result difference between the two function?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#switcher-default').bind('click', function() {
    $('body').removeClass('narrow');
    $('body').removeClass('large');
  });
});
```

the second function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#switcher-default').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('narrow');
    $('body').removeClass('large');
  });    
});
```

I am a newbie of **jQuery**, what's the difference between the above code? I feel that add or remove the bind `function`, the result is  the same.why the code adds the bind event?

Comment: have you read the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both will do the same thing attach `click` handler to `#switcher-default` element. `bind` is just other way of attaching any event to matched set of elements.

Using `bind` you can attach multiple events with common event handler on the element. The eventType should be separated by a space.

```
$('#foo').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
     //Do something
});
```

Answer (score 7):

It's the same, as you can see on jQuery's documentation regarding [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
This method is a shortcut for .bind('click', handler)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.  Both segments of code attach the function to the click event.  Bind is just useful if you don't know what type of event you will be binding to.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/3wCMJ/

Read the Jquery API Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/click/

With regards to the click() function:

> This method is a shortcut for .bind('click', handler)

Answer (score 2):

You can find your answer by reading the [`click()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

> This method is a shortcut for .bind('click', handler) in the first two
>   variations, and .trigger('click') in the third.

And also [`bind()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) suggests using `on()` instead of `bind()` in version 1.7 and above:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements.